# 8-bit read / write of BMP file

Tags: c++, io, bmp

I have a problem copying the bmp file. How do you load it into memory (with the option of editing pixels) and save it elsewhere? Without the use of external libraries.

I attach what I was able to do. The loading function probably works correctly. Writer no.

I need help creating a write function. And possible verification of the reading function

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

uint8_t* datBuff[2] = { nullptr, nullptr }; 
uint8_t* pixels = nullptr; 
BITMAPFILEHEADER* bmpHeader = nullptr; 
BITMAPINFOHEADER* bmpInfo = nullptr; 
int LoadBMP(const char* location);
int SaveNewBmp(const char* location);

int main()
{

}

int LoadBMP(const char* location) {

    std::ifstream file(location, std::ios::binary);
    if (!file)
    {
        std::cout << "Failure to open bitmap file.\n";

        return 1;
    }

    datBuff[0] = new uint8_t[sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)];
    datBuff[1] = new uint8_t[sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)];

    file.read((char*)datBuff[0], sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
    file.read((char*)datBuff[1], sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));

    bmpHeader = (BITMAPFILEHEADER*)datBuff[0];
    bmpInfo = (BITMAPINFOHEADER*)datBuff[1];

    if (bmpHeader->bfType != 0x4D42)
    {
        std::cout << "File \"" << location << "\" isn't a bitmap file\n";
        return 2;
    }

    pixels = new uint8_t[bmpInfo->biSizeImage];

    file.seekg(bmpHeader->bfOffBits);
    file.read((char*)pixels, bmpInfo->biSizeImage);

    return 0;
}

int SaveNewBmp(const char* location) {
    std::ofstream file(location, std::ios::binary);
    if (!file)
    {
        std::cout << "Failure to open bitmap file.\n";

        return 1;
    }

    file.write((char*)datBuff[0], sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
    file.write((char*)datBuff[1], sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));

    file.write((char*)pixels, bmpInfo->biSizeImage);
    return 0;
}
```

Have any ideas?

I can't use custom libraries
Consider the case of an 8 bit per pixel file. No other.

Comment: Does the reading and writing work?

Comment: No, only reading works. I don't know how to write so that the bitmap can be read.

Comment: You haven't actually told us what the problem is with this program.

Comment: I was editing the entry

Comment: When dealing with *bytes*, prefer to use `uint8_t`.  There is no guarantee that a `char`, signed or unsigned, is 8-bits.

Comment: I do it for both reasons. This is part of the project. By the way, I want to learn something new. And of course I can't use custom libraries in this project

Comment: It's still not clear what your problem is. But it looks like a good opportunity to learn debugging [here](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I have clarified my problem

Comment: You are not even reading the BMP data correctly to begin with. See [Bitmap Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/bitmap-storage), they're are details you are not accounting for. Like, for instance, `biSizeImage` can be 0 for RGB bitmaps. And that a color table may be present that you are ignoring.

Comment: Consider the case of an 8 bit per pixel file. No other.